# Promises vs Loop in JavaScript: how to avoid Too Many Requests and run simultaneously

Tags: javascript, api, axios, promise

On past few days I am trying to solve a situation involving API requests and Promises.
First of all, I am using [Axios-rate-limit](https://www.npmjs.com/package/axios-rate-limit) to manage requests at maximum of 30 per minute.

```
const requestTiny = axiosRateLimit(axios.create({'baseURL': '*****'}), {maxRequests: 30, perMilliseconds: 60500})
```

The main function is *syncProducts* as follows:

```
export const syncProducts = async (req, res) => {
    let productsBN = []
    let products = await getProductsERP('BN')
    for (let prod of products) {
        const product = await getProductERP(prod.store, prod.id)
        productsBN.push(product)
    }
    res.status(201).json(productsBN)
}
```

*getProductsERP* returns IDs and then *getProductERP* returns details of each product. *BN* is the store. This code does the job. I do not get Too Many Requests errors.

But now I need to grab data from multiple stores. The API request limit is per store. So, run stores in parallel is much faster.

First attempt was duplicate some lines for store *ORL*. As expected, code runs line by line and second store has to wait first store to finish.

```
export const syncProducts = async (req, res) => {
    let productsORL = [], productsBN = []
    let prodsBN = await getProductsERP('BN')
    for (let prod of prodsBN) {
        const product = await getProductERP(prod.store, prod.id)
        productsBN.push(product)
    }
    let prodsORL = await getProductsERP('ORL')
    for (let prod of prodsORL) {
        const product = await getProductERP(prod.store, prod.id)
        productsORL.push(product)
    }
    res.status(201).json(productsBN.concat(productsORL))
}
```

Based on [this](https://www.techiediaries.com/promise-all-map-async-await-example/) I tried to implement the same logic but using Promises.

```
export const syncProducts = async (req, res) => {
    let productsORL = [], productsBN = []
    Promise.all([
        getProductsERP('ORL').then(async products => {
            productsORL = await Promise.all(products.map(async prod => await getProductERP(prod.store, prod.id)))
        }),
        getProductsERP('BN').then(async products => {
            productsBN = await Promise.all(products.map(async prod => await getProductERP(prod.store, prod.id)))
        })
    ])
    .then(res.status(201).json(productsBN.concat(productsORL)))
    .catch(error => res.status(409).json(error))
}
```

The problem is while *getProductsERP* is running, Axios-rate-limit works well and both stores run in parallel (desired behavior).
When *getProductERP* runs, it starts all the requests together, causing Too Many Requests error.

What am I doing wrong? How to make *getProductERP* promises to respect API limits?

PS: I tried to resume as much as possible. If I am missing some important information to evaluate solution, just let me know and I will update the code.
Thanks,

Comment: `products.map(async prod => await getProductERP(prod.store, prod.id))` starts all requests in parallel. map doesn't know anything about async.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is what you're going for.

```
// Gets products for one store, sequentially.
async function getProducts(storeCode) {
  const products = [];
  for (const {store, id} of await getProductsERP(storeCode)) {
    products.push(await getProductERP(store, id));
  }
  return products;
}

// Gets products for multiple stores in parallel.
export const syncProducts = async (req, res) => {
    const products = await Promise.all(getProducts('BN'), getProducts('ORL'));
    res.status(201).json(products.flat());
}
```